# Filter multiple rows of data based on one row's data

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have flight segment data that I'm trying to filter out a bit, so my dataset is a more manageable size and hopefully make my life easier. Every row is a flight segment that I will later group together by acid, index, and date to make a single flight record.
Example table:

| acid | index | date | segment | us_air |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| xyz | 123 | 2020-10-01 | 1 | 1 |
| xyz | 123 | 2020-10-01 | 2 | 0 |
| xyz | 123 | 2020-10-01 | 3 | 1 |
| abc | 456 | 2020-10-02 | 1 | 0 |
| abc | 456 | 2020-10-02 | 2 | 0 |
| def | 789 | 2020-10-03 | 1 | 1 |
| def | 789 | 2020-10-03 | 2 | 1 |

Rows 1, 2, and 3 with be one record, 4 and 5 another, and 6 and 7 another.

The issue: I need to filter out rows where us_air=0, unless it equals 1 in a different row with the same combination of acid, index, and date. But I don't want the rows grouped/aggregated by these three columns yet.

End result should look like this:

| acid | index | date | segment | us_air |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| xyz | 123 | 2020-10-01 | 1 | 1 |
| xyz | 123 | 2020-10-01 | 2 | 0 |
| xyz | 123 | 2020-10-01 | 3 | 1 |
| def | 789 | 2020-10-03 | 1 | 1 |
| def | 789 | 2020-10-03 | 2 | 1 |

This is the query I've been testing out:

```
CREATE TABLE table2 AS (
SELECT * 
FROM table1 
WHERE acid IN (SELECT acid 
              FROM table1 
              WHERE us_air=1) AND 
    index IN (SELECT index 
              FROM table1 
              WHERE us_air=1) AND
    date IN (SELECT date 
             FROM table1 
             WHERE us_air=1));
```

I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a window function to achieve this.  Partitioning by `(acid, index, date)`, every row
in the `check_us` CTE will have a `has_us` column with the sum of the `us_air` values for that partition.  The main query can exclude rows where `has_us` is 0.

```
with check_us as (
  select *, sum(us_air) over (partition by acid, index, date) as has_us
    from table1
)
select acid, index, date, segment, us_air
  from check_us
 where has_us > 0
 order by acid, date, segment;
```

Comment: Good answer except the `partition by` needs the 3 columns acid, index, date. So `over (partition by acid, index, date)`. This is because as currently stands a row containing the same `acid' but different index and/or date but without us_air=1 would still be selected. Try ( 'xyz', 789, '2010-10-04', 1, 0).